# Success function not being triggered when rendering a JSON response in Rails 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using the jQuery's `$.get` function to get a JSON response from the server.

```
$.get(SITE_EDIT_HOME_URL,{key: key},function(r){
   r = JSON.parse(r);
   console.log(r);
});
```

And this is how I receive the request and send a response

```
def group_fields
   respond_to do |format|
       format.js do
           @group_fields = @site.theme.group(params[:key],@site);
           return render json: @group_fields
       end
   end
end
```

Inspecting the network, this is what Chrome receives as a response:

```
{"type":"group","fields":[1,2,3,4]}
```

A proper JSON string. But the success callback function is not executed and no errors are shown. What is wrong? How can I make this work? Do I HAVE to create the `group_fields.js`? I tested and this last idea works, but I lose the context of the callback function.

Thanks in advance

Comment: if the success callback function is not getting executed, how are verifying chrome received the response `r`? also, you dont need to `return render`, just `render` is fine

Comment: i verify it with the inspector. inspect elements > network. and I used return because there was another render below it before I posted. changing it won't affect the situation

Comment: does changing `get` to `getJSON` and `format.js` to `format.json` do anything? because you have multiple render types, i'm wondering if its not finding the proper one.

Comment: great idea. i does. what was the problem? i'm aware the request type is changed, but why do chrome receive a response but does nothing with it?

Comment: I wonder why I got downvoted. This is a reasonable question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing `get` to `getJSON` and `format.js` to `format.json` should solve the issue. it likely stems from the mime type mismatching because you have multiple different formats.

as seen [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/InstanceMethods/respond_to#note_content-14), there are various different types mapped to the formats. the ambiguity of not specifying json probably caused a mismatch in type, and rails couldnt return properly

Answer (score 1):

You need to try code below. You have to change your format into `respond_to format json` because you access from jquery and then the respond should come back to the jquery.

```
def group_fields
   @group_fields = @site.theme.group(params[:key], @site)
   respond_to do |format|
       format.html { render :nothing => true }
       format.json { render json: @group_fields}
     end
   end
end
```

**jQuery**

When the respond from controller is in json format, you did not parse into JSON. Try to do below:

```
$.get(SITE_EDIT_HOME_URL,{key: key},function(r){
   console.log(r);
})
.done(function() {
  console.log(r);
})
.fail(function() {
  console.log(r);
})
.always(function() {
  console.log(r);
});
```

I hope this help you.